# I have three columns and want to get value on criteria of two

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Example:

[image]

now i want to get pstatus(i.e. previous month status matching with id without using `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`.

Comment: You ask for a formula but dont want to use one of the most powerful combinations a formula can use? Why? Also, what have you come up with so far yourself? I would go with: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:$C1,3,FALSE),"")` in cel `D2`

Comment: i have 13k records and at each refresh it take 10 mins to calculate.